# Show that the chromatic number of a Series Parallel graph is at most 3

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, graph-minors

Although it is "well known" that a (simple) series parallel graph has chromatic number at most 3, I cannot seem to find a proof of this statement anywhere.

Does anyone know how to prove the statement?

It may be related to the fact that series parallel graphs are K4 minor free.

Comment: are you permitting multiple edges? hence your series paralell graph must not be simple?

Comment: I am only considering simple graphs. I have edited the question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every series-parallel graph (SPG) may be coloured with at most $3$ colours *such that their source and sink are coloured differently* (a P-colouring). This is clearly true for the base case, a single edge.

Suppose we have two P-coloured SPGs; the first's source and sink are coloured with colours $a$ and $b$, the second's $c$ and $d$ respectively. By permuting colours

- we can make $b=c$ and $a\ne d$, whereby we can form a P-coloured series composition of the two graphs
- we can make $a=c$ and $b=d$, whereby we can form a P-coloured parallel composition of the two graphs

Since all SPGs are formed by series and parallel compositions from the single edge, this shows by induction that all SPGs have a P-colouring, i.e. a $3$-colouring.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it is very clear. I just have one question concerning the formalization: what are we inducting on exactly? On the number of compositions? For example would the induction hypothesis be: For all SPG of n-1 compositions we assume they are 3 colorable. Then we would just show using your explanation that n compositions would also be 3 colorable?

Comment: @phil The set of all SPGs is not parametrised by a number. These graphs simply share the property that they are either (1) a single edge, (2) the series composition of two SPGs or (3) the parallel composition of the same. Thus the SPGs form an _inductive set_; induction proceeds by verifying that the existence of a P-colouring is preserved across the set's generators (and I learned about them in MA4207 Mathematical Logic at the National University of Singapore).